# SQL запрос на вставку рандомных данных из других таблиц?

Tags: sql

Есть

- таблица вопросов `Questions(id,Vopros,DisciplinaId....)`,
- таблица экзаменов `Exams(id,...,DisciplinaId,CountQuestions)`,
- таблица пользователей `Users (id,....,GroupId)` с указанием группы, к которой принадлежит студент
- таблица успеваемости `Uspevaemost (UserId,EkzamenId,VoprosId, [Otvet] )`

Алгоритм такой:

1. добавление данных в таблицу экзаменов Exams- 100 вопросов (`CountQuestions`) по дисциплине (`DisciplinaId`) для группы (`GroupId`).
2. Взять `id` студентов из `GroupId`
3. Взять `id` вопросов из `DisciplinaId`
4. Сгенерировать данные и занести в таблицу `Uspevaemost`
     `order by rand()`   с указанием `limit 100 (CountQuestions)`
   т.е. нужно не все вопросы записать, а только 100 рандомных по каждому студенту, который принадлежит данной группе и по дисциплине, которая указана.

Вообщем нагородил и не справлюсь.

Запутался, как написать запрос на генерацию. Подскажите пожалуйста.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id_ekzamena=$_GET["id_ekzamena"];   //ЭКЗАМЕН
$count_voprosov=$_GET["limit"];      //Количество вопросов
$id_group=$_GET["id_group"];         //Какой группе студентов добаляем тесты- вернёт айдишники студентов в группе
$viborka_studentov =$this->Vipolnit_Zapros("SELECT idstudents as id FROM Studentsingroups WHERE idgroups=".$id_group);
//$count =count($viborka_studentov);
foreach ($viborka_studentov  as $element) {
    $this->Vipolnit_Zapros("INSERT INTO uspevaemostekzameni (IdVoprosa,IdEkzamena,IdUser) 
                                SELECT  vopros.id as IdVoprosa,'".$id_ekzamena."' AS IdEkzamena,".$element['id']." AS IdUser FROM vopros ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$count_voprosov);
}
```